# i have set $config['per_page'] = 20 but it get only two result

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

i am using codeigniter pagination with per page 20 result but it get only two result when i click on pagination mean page number like 2, 3, 4
following is my controller

```
function restaurant_listing()
    {
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'admin/restaurant/restaurant_listing/';
        //$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        //$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@','',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->restaurant_model->record_count();
        $config['per_page'] = 20;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<b>';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
        $data["results"] = $this->restaurant_model->restlisting($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/restaurant_listing', $data, true);
        $this->load->view('admin/template', $data); 
    }
```

my view file contain

```
<div class="pagination"> <?php echo $links; ?> </div>
```

here i am showing pagination

Comment: Print this and see what you get: $this->restaurant_model->record_count();

Comment: i have print $this->restaurant_model->record_count(); and i got 163

Comment: and what it shows `count($this->restaurant_model->restlisting)` ??

Comment: please post your model code here

Comment: please share your query here.

Answer (score 0):

maybe can fix your code i use this code for pagnation

controller code

```
public restaurant_listing()
{

$restaurant=$this->uri->segment(4);

$limit_ti=20;
if(!$restaurant):
offset_ti = 0;
else:
$offset_ti = $restaurant;
endif;


$this->load->model('Restaurant_model');// call model
$this->load->library('pagination'); // call library

$query=$this->restaurant_model->restlisting($limit_ti,$offset_ti); // geting an article 

$total_page = $this->restaurant_model->record_count(); // count row

 /** Pagination **/
 $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/restaurant/restaurant_listing/'; 
 $config['total_rows'] =$total_page->num_rows();
 $config['per_page'] = 20; 
 $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
 $config['num_links'] = 10;
 $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
 $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<b>';
 $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data = array('query' => $query,'page'=>$restaurant);

    $data['content'] = 'admin/restaurant_listing';
    $this->load->view('template', $data);

}
```

models code

```
function restlisting($limit,$ofset){
$query=$this->db->query("select * from *name table* order by id ASC LIMIT $ofset,$limit");
return $query;
}

function record_count(){
$query=$this->db->query("select * from *name table*");
return $query;
}
```

view code

```
<div class="pagination"><?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); // call the pagnation?></div>
```